# Getting trustworthy results from small samples and small population

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, small-sample, psychology, social-science

I am an undergraduate student of psychology from Indonesia.

Right now I am doing a mini research project where I correlate geographical data to outcomes at the provincial level. The hypotheses is that geographical characteristic A is associated positively with outcomes XYZ. However, there are only 34 provinces in Indonesia, which certainly makes it very difficult to get reliable results, and probably impossible to detect small effect sizes. Right now, my analyses have yielded non-significant positive r coefficients.

However, I do have data on provincial characteristics from different years, e.g 2015-2020. I am wondering if there is a statistical method where I can somehow "synthesize" the nonsignificant results from different years into reliable(?) significant r coefficients?

I hope I articulated my intentions clearly. I have no educational background in mathematics so I'm wondering if any of you here could help me, and pardon if I misunderstood some statistical concepts here. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There are ways of synthesising different analyses, in your case different years, but they are for independent data and I imagine there is dependency between years here.

Comment: If you are not interested in change over time you could average each variable over years and then re-run your correlations on the averages which should have higher reliability.

Comment: I see, but should I do something in light of the nonsignificant p-values?

Comment: The data is the data. If it turns out that the relationships are too weak to detect that is what they are. But perhaps I was not clear enough as if you have more reliable measurements as I suggested you might be better equipped to detect something.